# Are later versions of the Front-End compatible with older Kernels?

Tags: front-end, remote-access, version-6

At my graduate school, all of the clusters still use version-6, and I only have version-7 and version-8 installed on my computer. I would like to use those machines remotely. Are either of the versions I have compatible with the version-6 kernel?

Comment: What happens if you try to set up one of those machines in the kernel configuration options?

Comment: @acl good question. I'm having I think other issues with communication, but the kernel is launched remotely, and then the nothing happens on my local machine. It keeps waiting. I think its because its attempting to use ports I don't have open on my local machine, but I have not tested that, yet. However, I thought a general compatibility question was viable.

Comment: Manually connect to the remote kernels.

Comment: You may be able to ask them to upgrade the software, since they may already have the site license. I have the same situation here in my school, and I successfully asked them updated the Mathematica to the newest version.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best thing to do is to test whether you can make the connection manually:

Start Mathematica on your local machine. 
On the toolbar, navigate to *Evaluation ► Kernel Configuration Options*.
Add a new kernel and configure it. In the dialog, click on *Add* ... and a *Kernel Configuration* dialog appears.
Enter an appropriate name for your remote kernel.
Under *Basic Options*, verify that *Launch On* is set to *Local machine*. Additionally, clear the field, *Kernel program*.
Click on the *Advanced Options* switch. In the text field called *Arguments to MLOpen*, enter:

```
-LinkMode Listen -LinkProtocol TCPIP
```

Click *OK* and open up a new Mathematica notebook.
On the toolbar, navigate to *Evaluation ► Notebook's Kernel* and click on the name of the kernel that you just created.
Evaluate the command:

```
$Version
```

inside the notebook. Instead of printing
Mathematica's version number, a message box appears:

```
MathLink Alert
Link created on:
```

After this message is a string of characters. This string of characters is a `linkname`. Record the `linkname` so that you can use it later, and click *OK* to close the dialog.
The title bar of the notebook should still say *Running...* at the top.

While, the local machine is still running that notebook, connect to the remote machine and launch the Mathematica kernel. Inside the kernel, run the command:

```
$ParentLink = LinkConnect["linkname", LinkProtocol->"TCPIP"]
```

Where "linkname" is the `linkname` you recorded earlier in quotation marks. For example, if the `linkname` you saw was:

```
port1@machine.domain.com,port2@machine.domain.com
```

You would run:

```
$ParentLink = LinkConnect[
                "port1@machine.domain.com,port2@machine.domain.com",
                LinkProtocol->"TCPIP"]
```

The notebook that is open on the local machine prints out the version of Mathematica you remotely connected to. This indicates that the local machine is successfully using the remote kernel.

Comment: Do I leave the launch command alone?

Comment: You leave the local notebook which says "Running..." at the top alone and then perform the rest of the manual connection from the remote machine. At the very end, you will see the version number of the remote machine appear in the local front-end.

Comment: That's not what I mean, in the "Kernel Configuration Options" do I leave the "Launch Command" under "Advanced Options" alone?

Comment: Overall, interesting approach. I'll make the attempt tonight, and let you know.

Comment: My apologies, I haven't tried this, yet. Probably this weekend.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, older kernels are compatible with newer front ends.  I think this is why the `` Version5`Graphics` ``, `` Version6`Graphics` `` and `` Version7`Graphics` `` packages exist. (Simply to ensure compatibility of graphics.  From a short look at .tr files once I got the impression these get loaded when older kernels are used.)

Regarding managing to create a connection, the [Remote Kernel Strategies](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7250/) package is the most robust and most hassle-free approach I know.

Unfortunately when I use a remote kernel, my [front end tends to freeze occasionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717211/understanding-kernel-frontend-communication-why-does-my-front-end-freeze), but others didn't manage to reproduce this, so you may be safe.  Just try the dynamic example from that link to test this.

Comment: +1, thanks for the reference. I'll give a try alongside [Searke's recommendation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/391/52) tonight.