# Mathematica Parellelization on HPC

Tags: parallelization, licensing, high-performance-clusters

I'm currently using *Mathematica* on a High Performance Cluster (HPC) which consists of many compute nodes each with around 16 cores. I currently run my *Mathematica* script on 20 of the nodes that invokes 10 cores and 10 of the subkernels licenses in Parallel, meaning I use 20 Mathkernel licenses and 200 subkernel licenses.

The problem is we have limited Mathkernel licenses (36, and for me to be using 20 of them is unfair on everyone else!) although ample subkernel licenses (288). Is there a way I can just use a single (or at least fewer) Mathkernel licenses to invoke the 200 subkernels I need?

Currently in each of the 20 scripts I just have

```
LaunchKernels[10];
ParellelTable[....];
```

which launches the 10 local subkernels on each node, but could I specify different nodes to launch subkernels on perhaps? Thereby I would only need to launch one Mathkernel which could invoke the 200 subkernels spread across the compute nodes.

Comment: Are you asking or boasting? :)

Comment: Yes, this is possible, and I am doing this right now.  But how it can be done is dependent on the grid engine your HPC cluster is using as well as details of the local setup.

Comment: @belisarius hehe @Szabolcs The grid engine is `PBS Pro`.

Comment: @fpghost I spent a day and a half on just figuring this out, so I uploaded a solution to bitbucket.  It's not for PBS, but looking at it might save you some time.  See my answer.

Comment: @Szabolcs  thanks very much, I'll have a play around and see how I get on.

Comment: @fpghost If you get it working, can you document your solution, like I did, and put a link here?  Even if it's valid for your cluster only, it would have saved me so much time to see an existing solution.

Comment: @Szabolcs yes, will do.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you need to launch subkernels across several nodes on a HPC cluster is the following:

1. Figure out how to request several compute nodes for the *same* job
2. Find the names of the nodes that have been allocated for your job
3. Find out how to launch subkernels on these nodes from within the main kernel

All of these depend on the grid engine your cluster is using, as well as your local setup, and you'll need to check its docs and ask your administrator about the details.  I have an example for our local setup (complete with a jobfile), which might be helpful for you to study:

https://bitbucket.org/szhorvat/crc/src

Our cluster uses the Sun Grid Engine.  The names of the nodes (and information about them) are listed in a "hostfile" which you can find by retrieving the value of the `PE_HOSTFILE` environment variable.  (I think this works the same way with PBS, except the environment variable is called something else.)

Note that if you request multiple nodes in a single job file, the job script will be run on only one of the nodes, and you'll be launching the processes across all nodes manually (at least on SGE and PBS).

[Launching processes on different nodes](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/5255/multi-node-jobs-with-sun-grid-engine-without-mpi) is usually possible with `ssh`: just run `ssh nodename command` to run `command`.  You may also need to set up passphraseless authentication if it is not set up by default.  To launch subkernels, you'll need to pass the `-f` option to `ssh` to let it return immediately after it has launched the remote process.

Some setups use `rsh` instead of `ssh`.  To launch a command *in the background* using `rsh`, you'll need to do

```
rsh -n nodename "command >& /dev/null &"
```

To run the remote process in the background, it important to redirect the output (both stdout and stderr) because there's a bug in rsh (also described in its man page) that won't let it return immediately otherwise.

Another thing to keep in mind about `rsh` is that you can't `rsh` to the local machine, so you'll need to launch the subkernels which will run on the same machine as the main kernel without `rsh`.

See [my example](https://bitbucket.org/szhorvat/crc/src) for details.

Comment: How's the performance on the cluster? I'd be very wary of scaling problems with this many subkernels... also, last I tried, MathLink begins to crap out with hundreds of simultaneous connections.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I haven't run more than 60 kernels like this yet, and for my application the communication was minimal between the kernels, so I didn't notice any performance problems.  I'll try a very big job soon, just out of curiosity.

Comment: So to request several compute nodes for the same job I simplet do `qsub -l select=10:ncpus=10:mem=2gb subscript.sh` for example which would give me 10 nodes each with 10 cores. So far so good.

Comment: @fpghost Szabolcs's suggestion of using `ssh` should work, but given that you're using PBS, you might find [OSC `mpiexec`](https://www.osc.edu/~djohnson/mpiexec/index.php) preferable. I find it easier to use and much more reliable than the `ssh`-based method (N.B.: for other programs; *Mathematica* isn't available on any of the clusters I have access to). Despite the name, the programs you launch do not have to be compiled against an MPI library.

Comment: Still just figuring out what's going on in your `CRC.m`. Could you possibly explain the command     ``SubKernels`RemoteKernels`RemoteMachine[
    host,rsh <> " -n `1` \"" <> math <> 
      " -mathlink -linkmode Connect `4` -linkname '`2`' -subkernel -noinit >& /dev/null &\"",
    cores] `` is this the same as described in the Manual launching section of http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ParallelTools/tutorial/ConnectionMethods.html

Comment: @fpghost Yes, it's the same.  Also see [here](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/1085/605).  The `RemoteMachine` head just contains all the information needed by Mathematica to launch a subkernel: the host, the launch command, the number of subkernels to launch on that host.  Those backticked numbers are templates: the value will be automatically substituted.  See the page you linked for their meaning.  Here I had to use `rsh` to launch, but you will likely need `ssh` on your cluster.

Comment: @Szabolcs OK, thanks. What does the `<> ...<>` notation mean? Is it just to dereference the var? I think I just need to get the `PBSpro` equivalent to the env var `"PE_HOSTFILE"` then. I thought it was `PBS_NODEFILE` but that seems to be empty, hmm.

Comment: @fpghost <> is string join. `"asd" <> "123" === "asd123"`.

Comment: OK, I think I understand what is going on now. I have changed the rsh line to `ssh="/usr/bin/ssh"` and other refs to `rsh` to `ssh` in `CRC.m`. I have also used `PBS_NODEFILE` (which seems to give a path to a file when I print it now) for the location of hosts.  I am getting errors like `Part::take: Cannot take positions 1 through 2 in {node052}.` however.

Comment: I currently have ``SubKernels`RemoteKernels`RemoteMachine[
    host,
    ssh -x -f -l  <> " -n `1` \"" <> math <>
      " -mathlink -linkmode Connect `4` -linkname '`2`' -subkernel -noinit\"",
    cores]``

Comment: Actually is this error to do with reading the hostfile?

Comment: @fpghost The format of the hostfile seems to be different for PBS.  On SGE it's a table where the first column is the hostnames and the second one is the number of cores.  You'll have to examine a hostfile on PBS and see what it contains.

Comment: Ah, it just contains one column with `node053
node055,.....` the number of cores is always 16 though, so I can put that in manually by just removing the second arg of `CRC`.

Comment: `ParallelTable::nopar: No parallel kernels available; proceeding with sequential evaluation.` is what I get now. With my hostfile in the above format, I changed things in `CRC.m` to be like `hosts = Import[hostfile, "List"];
  $ConfiguredKernels = Join[$ConfiguredKernels, CRCKernel @@@ Rest[hosts]]` and changed `CRCKernel` to ``CRCKernel[host_String]:=
  SubKernels`RemoteKernels`RemoteMachine[
    host,
    ssh -x -f   <> " -n `1` \"" <> math <>
      " -mathlink -linkmode Connect `4` -linkname '`2`' -subkernel -noinit\"",
    16]`` as well as the original definition.

Comment: You didn't quote `ssh` as a string ...  Also I'd recommend that you don't use `CRC.m` directly.  Instead read it, understand what it does, and re-build it step by step, verifying that each step works.  The first thing for you would be figuring out how to start commands on a remote machine using ssh from the terminal (not from within Mathematica).

Comment: I do think I understand it reasonably well now, although I am a little rusty on some Mathematica syntax to do with string joins etc. How is; ``SubKernels`RemoteKernels`RemoteMachine[
    host,
    ssh <> " -x -f -n `1` \"" <> "/cm/shared/apps/Mathematica_8.0.4/bin/math" <>
      " -mathlink -linkmode Connect `4` -linkname '`2`' -subkernel -noinit\"",
    16]``? On these HPC `math` is not an alias and full path is needed- the error I now get is `bash: math: command not found

KernelObject::rdead: Subkernel connected through remote[node053] appears dead.` (with or without abs path in above)

Comment: I defined `ssh="/usr/bin/ssh" already in place of your `rsh` def.

Comment: @Szabolcs totally baffled as to why it's giving `bash: math: command not found` when I am passing the absolute path to `math` everywhere I can in `CRC.m`. Also even from the terminal simply doing `ssh  node055 /cm/shared/apps/Mathematica_8.0.4/bin/math` gives the familiar `Input[]` but then times out after 15 secs.

Comment: @Szabolcs Hi, I finally got this working. I don't know much about Package writing, so have just placed my needed Kernel Launch commands in `job.nb` along with parsing commands for `hostfile`. If I try to use your package as a template then add it to my notebook with `Needs` things no longer work for some reason. I don't know much about package writing so I am prob doing something stupid there. If you like however I can make a package from my notebook and upload to bitbucket and perhaps you could take a look so we could publish it there for others using `PBSpro` in the future?

Comment: @OleksandrR. I think you are right MathLink does seem to be dying for me with 190 Kernels. Despite getting there in the end it now takes vastly longer than when I had 19 single MathKernels with 10 local slaves each.

Comment: @Szabolcs Is my understand correct, that the ssh only used once to start the subkernels, and the communication between the subkernel and the main kernel are still using TCPIP? Our university recently bought a big machine, but it seems that I cannot using more than one nodes and I'm suspect that may because the TCPIP are Blocked.

Comment: @xslittlegrass Yes, that's correct. SSH is only used to start up the remote kernel, but once the kernel is started, SSH terminates.  It doesn't do tunneling or that sort of thing.

Comment: @Szabolcs, Your Links are not working. Could you please update them

Answer (score 6):

**Update**

The node names in a job can be access through environment variables such as PBS_NODEFILE and HOSTNAME, so that launching subkernels on the correct nodes [can be automated](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31834/1364).

---

I'm also trying the run more subKernels from a main kernel on HPC. I usually apply an interaction job on the HPC and run math kernels on it, and then connect back to the front end on may laptop. My waiting time for the queue of the interactive job is very short so it is convenient for me to do the work in the interactive way. Here is how I did, it may not be the same, but hope it would help.

**Apply a interative job**

```
qsub -V -I -l walltime=01:00:00,nodes=2:ppn=16 -A hpc_atistartup
```

it will return something like this:

> ```
> qsub: waiting for job 48488.mike3 to start
> qsub: job 48488.mike3 ready
>
> --------------------------------------
> Running PBS prologue script
> --------------------------------------
> PBS has allocated the following nodes:
>
> mike054
> mike067
>
> A total of 32 processors on 2 nodes allocated
> ---------------------------------------------
> Check nodes and clean them of stray processes
> ---------------------------------------------
> Checking node mike054 15:43:46 
> Checking node mike067 15:43:48 
> Done clearing all the allocated nodes
> ------------------------------------------------------
> Concluding PBS prologue script - 01-Sep-2013 15:43:48
> ------------------------------------------------------
> [aaa@mike054 ~]$
> ```

We can see I get nodes mike054 and mike067, and the shell is on node mike054.

**Start remote master kernel**

From the menu of the local front end(my laptop), Evaluation ==> Kernel Configuration Options , add a remote Kernel, here I added one called superMike. Select "Advanced Options" and fill it with "-LinkMode Listen -LinkProtocol TCPIP".

[image]

Then run a command in a notebook, for example `$Version`. It would pop out a window like this:

[image]

The port and IP address should be different than mine.

With this pop up window opened, go to your shell at the HPC we just get, run the command `math` to launch command line mathematica. After I get the mathematica shell, enter

```
$ParentLink = LinkConnect["50013@127.0.0.1,50014@127.0.0.1", LinkProtocol->"TCPIP"]
```

and hit enter. Then hit the "OK" key of that pop up window. If it successfully connected, it would pop up a message window with

```
Out[1]:=LinkObject[50013@127.0.0.1,50014@127.0.0.1, 59, 2]
```

and the `$Version` command should return the results:

[image]

For details of the remote kernel connection, see the post [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/388/are-later-versions-of-the-front-end-compatible-with-older-kernels).

**Start subKernels**

Open the Remote Kernels tab in Evaluation ==> Parallel Kernel Configuration, clink "Add Host" to add other nodes we get in the interactive job. In this case I get nodes mike054 and mike067, and the shell I get is on node mike054. So I will add mike067 by fill the Hostname, set the number of kernels and check "Enable".

[image]

After that we can go to Evaluation ==> Parallel Kernel status, and check whether the subKernel are working. If everything went successfully we can see something like this

[image]

We can see that we've launched 16 subKernels on node mike054 and 16 subKernels on node mike067.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Hi,xslittlegrass! Do you know how to do it without front end? The network of the HPC which I use is not fast enough to use a front end. And I didn't understand Szabolcs's method. Does he achieve the same effect as yours(to parallel computation across different nodes)?

Comment: @matheorem [Here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31834/1364) is the (better) way to do in the code :)

Comment: Thank you for the information! I am reading it. I have a question. I can't understand the step **Start remote master kernel**. In the Mathematica doc "ParallelTools/tutorial/ConnectionMethods", it didn't say that we have to start remote master kernel. And I can understand why your method can launch a master kernel on remote node. Can explain it a little?

Comment: @matheorem that remote master kernel is just the default remote kernel we are in. Say if we get 2 nodes "mike1" and "mike2" from qsub and we are on "mike1". Then when you type "math" to launch mathematica kernel, it will launch a master kernel. This master kernel is what I was referring to. It is a "remote" kernel in the sense that the kernel is running on the hpc and the front end is running on my laptop. That's all I meant. After launching the master kernel, we can then launch the sub-kernels using the linked codes.

Comment: Now, I am sure that the first step **Start remote master kernel** is unnecessary. Just Add host in the `remote Kernels` tab, and then first `CloseKernels[]`, second `LauchKernels[]`, all the Kernels will be launched. This works on my HPC.

Comment: @matheorem I'm glade it works for you. For our hpc, we can not access the computational nodes directly from my local computer. I think that's why I need the remote master kernel in my case.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. In our framework it is like that: We have a *Mathematica* licence server hosting say 10 licences. I lately saw a screen dump from the server status and there, used Kernels and Subkernels were handled independently. This means, if everyone else is using *Mathematica* in a non-parallel way, I can take me all the Subkernels by going to the preferences and adjusting the number of used Subkernels in the Parallel tab

[image]