# Launching All Unoccupied Threads as Kernels [CPU Usage Assessment with Mathematica]

Tags: parallelization, kernel-startup

I'm working on a PC with 10 processor cores (20 threads), so it can support 20 concurrent computations.  I often run simulations in the background on my PC such that some fraction of these, say 12, are occupied.  I would like to write a function `myLaunchKernels[]` that launches (n) kernels, where (n) is the number of unoccupied processor threads [give or take two for system processes].  So in my dummy example, it would launch 8 kernels minus however many designated for system processes.  [This may seem trivial and for me (where I can usually remember how many are in use) it often is, but it might be useful to others using distributed computing or with [HPC applications](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20356/mathematica-parellelization-on-hpc?rq=1) with more cores and concurrent jobs.]

This essentially just requires an ability to - in Mathematica - do what one can do manually by looking at Task Manager in Windows and counting how many processes are active and consuming appreciable CPU power.  If this `numberActiveProcesses` function returned the 12 from the above example, it would be trivial to feed this into `LaunchKernels` after subtracting a couple for system usage.

It would be similar to the standard `$ProcessorCount`; is there a similar (maybe undocumented) function for detecting the number of threads in use at the moment?

Comment: On HPC clusters, it should be possible to query the number of available cores from the job scheduler. Actually, normally one requests a certain number of cores. I do not think that the concept of "free cores" is very clearly defined.  But on a cluster you are always expected to be a good citizen and use a certain number of cores, even if technically you could use more.